# Start a program muted, or permanently mute it

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, mute

(On 16.04 with Unity)

I have a particular program that makes an incredibly obnoxious sound whenever I start it up. I don't want to completely mute my system for a moment because sometimes I open it while on a call. I see I can mute it from the sound controls, but it's not permanent. So:

1. Is there any way to start a program muted?
2. If not, is there a way to permanently mute it? From PulseAudio config perhaps?

Comment: What program? If it doesn't have settings for that then there's nothing you can do at the OS or audio subsystem to selectively mute one program and not the others.

Comment: There must be, because it's possible to mute an individual program from the Sounds menu (Sound -> Applications -> check the Mute box).

Comment: Another way to phrase it: in `pavucontrol` I can mute an individual program. Is there a way to tell PulseAudio to keep the settings on that program for the next time I start it up, instead of reseting to the defaults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is old, but I thought I'd answer it for future visitors.

I solved this problem by setting the volume of the particular app to zero (instead of clicking the "mute" button).

I'm not sure why this works, but it keeps an app muted even if you close it and re-open it. I don't know if it works after a reboot though.

**EDIT:** I can now confirm that this method does work even after a reboot.